# Как отконвертировать ссылку

Tags: .htaccess, php

Привет народ, я хочу отконвертировать ссылку например download.php?key=293842349sd&time=120212 в такой вид (точно незнаю) download.php/293842349sd/120212p
знаю это можно зделать через htaccess, но не знаю как.

и второй вопрос как это реализовать без htaccess

заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download\.php/([^/]*)/([^/]*)p$ /download.php?key=$1&time=$2 [L]

http://www.domain.com/download.php?key=293842349sd&time=120212 
http://www.domain.com/download.php/293842349sd/120212p
```

Должно сработать

Comment: мне интересно, а, что ссылками делать они у меня в таком виде /index.php?action=article&article=new

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы реализовать то, о чем вы пишете, htaccess не нужен.

```
$query = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
if (preg_match('/\/(\d+)sd\/(\d+)p/', $query, $matches))
{
    $key = $matches[1];
    $time = $matches[2];
}
```

Comment: попробуем поже

Comment: не могу понять скрипт. разъясните $matches массив создается автоматом это я понял. также есть переменная $query результат URL. а вот, что подставлять в $matches для сравнения в preg_match.